# Child state loads parent state templateUrl in nested routes of UI-Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, templating

I'm using `UI-Router` module for routing. I have 2 states that router should match the urls with them according to nested routes laws :

```
// Dashboard
.state('dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "dashboard/views/index.html",
    controller: "DashboardController",
    ...
})

// Users
.state('users', {
    url: "/users",
    templateUrl: "users/views/index.html",
    controller: "UsersController",
    ...
})

// Single User
.state('users.id', {
    url: "/{id:(?:[a-z0-9_-]{3,16})}",
    templateUrl: "users/views/show.html",
    controller: "UserController",
    ...
})
```

also I have set a default route :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
```

**Problem :**

when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/#/users/testuser123`, it shows `index.html` from `users` state instead of `show.html` from `users.id` state. What's the Problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `users` within your url definition for `users.id` if you call `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/#/users/testuser123`

```
.state('users.id', {
    url: "/users/{id:(?:[a-z0-9_-]{3,16})}",
    templateUrl: "users/views/show.html",
    controller: "UserController",
    ...
})
```